# How to use google geocode's long and lat outside of internal scope?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope, google-geocoder

The return node is not set before geocode is done. How can I make sure the node is set to my desired values before it is returned?

```
function convertAddress(address) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var node = [0,0]

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      node = [latitude, longitude];
    }
  });
  return node;
}
```